# how to count the total amount of digits in a byte[] if you were to sum the array

Tags: c#, math

i want to make a function that counts the amount of digits once the value is sumed up

lets say i have this array

```
byte[] array = new byte[] { 200, 100, 200, 250, 150, 100, 200 };
```

once this is sumed up you'll have a value of 1200

you can get the amount of digits with these functions

```
Math.Floor(Math.Log10(1200)+1) // 4
```

but if i sum it up and there are too many values in the array i get an integer overflow

```
public decimal countDigits(byte[] array)
{
    decimal count = array[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
         count = Math.Log10(Math.Pow(count, 10)+array[i]);
    }

    return count;
}
```

this does give the correct output i want but this causes a integeroverflow if the count is greater than 28.898879583742193 (log10(decimal.MaxValue))

Comment: For fun, here's a one-line version that can still overflow: `public int countNumbers(byte[] array)
{
    return Math.Floor(Math.Log10(array.Select(b => (long)b).Sum()));
}`

Comment: Love that - you should update title to "300 - rare byte finally seen in the wild."

Comment: What your code does, and the example you gave are two different things.
Your code keeps increasing count, but you say you want the number of digits from the sum. And the method is called countOfNumbers. So what dou you really want?

Comment: `countNumbers` would just be `array.Length`, but the result of what you describe would simply be `4`, so it is  totally unclear to me what `countNumbers` is supposed to calculate.

Comment: Do you want the number of digits of the sum or the sum of the number of digits? I do not understand why you need this `Math.Pow`. It is not required to get the number of digits.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's a `BigInteger` data type that can sum up arbitrary (integer) values. It even has a `Log10` method, so it works very similar to a standard integer variable. The only limitation is that the result of `BigInteger.Log10` must be smaller than `Double.MaxValue`, but that sounds like a reasonable limitation. (10^1E308=10^10^308 is a really huge number)

Comment: If you use `BigInteger` to sum the values, probably performance is of no such concern, and you can just do a `ToString().Length` to get the amount of digits

Comment: @Jcl True. However, the `Log10` limitation is really theoretical only, you can't reach that value by just summing up bytes. Not this century, at least.

Comment: Agree, but on his algorithm (I haven't checked if it's right or not, but I think it isn't), he does a Log10 on every byte, would be just easier (and probably faster) to sum, then do a `ToString().Length` at the end, no need for even `Log10`

Answer (score 1):

Let's put a simple question: how many `byte`s should we sum in order to get *integer overflow* with `long`? The answer is simple: in the *worst case* (all bytes are of maximum possible value) it requires

```
long.MaxValue / byte.MaxValue + 1 = 36170086419038337 (~3.61e16) bytes
```

How long are we going to sum? Even if it requires just `1` cpu *tick* (`~ 0.1` ns) to get item from array and sum we require
`~3.6e6` seconds which is **41** day (or **82** days in case of `ulong`). If it's not your case (note, that array in C# can't have more than `2.1e9` items when we want at least `3.6e16`), then you can just sum as `long` (or `ulong`):

```
public static int countNumbers(byte[] array) {
  ulong sum = 0;

  foreach (byte item in array)
    sum += item;

  // How many digits do we have?
  return sum.ToString().Length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`i want to make a function that counts the amount of digits once the value is sumed up`

```
public decimal countNumbers(byte[] array)
{
    // sum the values...
    decimal sum = 0;

    foreach (byte value in array)
    {
         sum += value 
    }

    // ... then "count" the digits.
    return Math.Floor(Math.Log10(sum)+1);
}
```

This would be the code then, however your Question, the provided example and the naming of your method all imply different things so see if that helps, and if it does, please work on your naming.